# golang build with gcc instead of g++

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to build Go that is calling c++ created `.so` *(a.so)* file on Linux, but I found that the `go build .` command always builds with gcc **NOT** g++. I already put the `.cpp` in the root directory instead in subdirectory.

Here is the output of `go build` command

```
client.go:90:10: could not determine kind of name for C.Init
cgo:
gcc errors for preamble:
In file included from client.go:8:
a.h:34:1: error: unknown type name 'class'
   34 | class A {
      | ^~~~~
a.h:34:11: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
   34 | class A {
      |           ^               ^
```

Here is the `client.go` calling C code:

```golang
package main

// #cgo windows LDFLAGS: -la
// #cgo windows CXXFLAGS: -DWINDOWS
// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -liba
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L./libs
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -I./
// #include "a.h"
import "C"

func function() {
    handle, _ := dlOpen(PATH_TO_SO_FILE)
    blob := C.Init(handle)
}
```

Here is the dlOpen related code, wrote in Go:

```
// +build linux

package main

// #cgo linux LDFLAGS: -ldl
// #include <dlfcn.h>
// #include <stdlib.h>
import "C"

import "errors"
import "unsafe"

type Handle {
    c unsafe.Pointer
}

func dlOpen(filename string) (Handle, error) {
    ptr := C.CString(filename)
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(ptr))
    ret := C.dlopen(ptr, C.RTLD_LAZY)
    if ret != nil {
        return Handle{ret}, nil
    }
    return Handle{ret}, errors.New(C.GoString(C.dlerror()))
}
```

Here is the `a.h`

```
class A {
    public:
        Init(MHANDLE handle);
}
```

Comment: Set and export the `CC` environment variable [as documented](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with the cpp file.
You wrote in the go file `// #include "a.h"`.
Go currently compiles this as c and has no support for c++ and it looks like it will never have.
The only option you have is to make the header file valid in c.